# Neo4j.rb : friends-of-friends with whom the user has a lot of mutual friends with

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 1 Node and 1 Relation

Node - User

Basically I am working on solution to have list of friends-of-friends with whom the user has a lot of mutual friends with, also heigher mutual's will be at top.

Relation has 1 attribute status which should be 1 (it means user is friend, 0 means connection request is pending)

```
  Neo4j::ActiveBase.new_query.match(n: {StayPal: { uuid: "005d-46de- 
  9ab4-b54aa7a92a8a" }}).break.match('(n)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]- 
  (mutual)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(friends_of_friends: 
  `StayPal`)').break.match('(n)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(mutual2)- 
  [:connected_to {status: 1}]- 
  (friends_of_friends)').return('friends_of_friends, mutual2')
```

Cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:`StayPal` {uuid: {n_StayPal_uuid}}) MATCH (n)-[:connected_to 
{status: 1}]-(mutual)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(friends_of_friends: 
`StayPal`) MATCH (n)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(mutual2)- 
[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(friends_of_friends) RETURN 
friends_of_friends, mutual2
```

Please help me if I am doing it right? mutual2 should be array I think but its only giving 1 user with 1 friends_of_friend

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
MATCH (n:`StayPal` {uuid: {n_StayPal_uuid}})-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(mutual)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(friends_of_friends: `StayPal`) 
RETURN DISTINCT friends_of_friends , COLLECT(DISTINCT mutual), COUNT(mutual) as mutualCount 
ORDER BY mutualCount DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks Govind is there any way to add uniqness on mutualCount or all are uniq? and also if I want first 10 uniq mutuals as well in return?

Comment: there is issue in query it gives me some friends_of_friends which is already friend of n (having connection with status 1) @govind

Comment: `WHERE NOT(n)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(friends_of_friends)` is working fine and removed connection if already connected